# Organise utorrent downloads

Tags: utorrent

I would like organize my downloads. I need to keep music in music directory, books in books one. Currently I just cut downloaded source and paste it to my library. But this method is not good since source is not available for upload. How to solve this problem?

UPD
I have many downloads I I'm trying to tag them, but these files remains in the same directory. I found `Auto label` and `Label-Directory Mapping` under `Options->Preferences->Label` . As far as I understood in `Label-Directory Mapping`  I can set paths to labels, but I can't change default values - `audio`, `document`,`video`.

Comment: Select the correct directory before starting your downloads.

Comment: And move current torrents with right click, advanced, set download location

Answer (score 2):

**uTorrent** comes with a "*labeling*" feature to keep a better organization of your (current) downloads:

[image]

with the help of these labels, a labeled torrent will be moved to its corresponding directory when the download has finished.

Its a tagging mechanism that the user could use at runtime to tag (then move) the current downloads:

[image]

Source and tutorial:

http://torrentfreak.com/use-utorrent-to-organize-your-bittorrent-downloads/

---

If you are in need of a fully automated way, then a 3rd party monitoring application is need (or in defect programming knowledges). I'll suggest you to use **Directory Monitor** to be listening on the downloaded sort of files and move them to specific directories depending on the conditions that you choose (such as for example its file extensions).

[image]

It is a shareware app, but sincerelly is the most complete choice and is not a high-price product, anyways If I remember good the trial mode has no expiration, only feature limitations.

Comment: I have many downloads I I'm trying to tag them, but these files remains in the same directory. I found "Auto label" and "Label-Directory Mapping" under Options->Preferences->Label . As far as I understood in "Label-Directory Mapping"  I can set paths to labels, but I can't change default values - audio, document,video.